# Fast way to extract exact file from archive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, extract, tar

I'm currently using this command to extract only 1 .sql file from archive

```
tar xzvf *.gz *.sql
```

It's located on first level inside .tar.gz. like:

- archive.tar.gz

  - bla.sql
  - folder
  - ...

But seems this commands scans whole tar.gz and it takes very long time.

Is there any fast way? any suggestions?

Comment: A `.tar.gz` file is a gzip compressed continuous stream of data. If you want to get single files out of it, you have to decompress everything (you cannot know in advance where the specific file will be located in the stream)

Comment: That command doesn't extract "only 1 .sql file"... The wildcards are expanded before `tar` even starts, so the results of the command are highly dependent on what is in your current directory. You could end up running `tar xzvf foo.gz test.tar.gz blah.gz really_goofy.tar.cpio.gz test.sql blah.sql foo.sql goober.sql` - which may not be exactly what you want...

Answer (score 1):

- archive.tar.gz

  - bla.sql
  - folder
  - ...

If you want to extract only bla.sql, just add the full path of the file (into the archive) in parameter :

```
tar xvf archive.tar.gz bla.sql
```

---

Another example :

- test.tar.gz

  - foo.sql
  - Folder

    - bar.sql
    - baz

If you want to extract `foo.sql` and `baz` :

```
tar xvf test.tar.gz foo.sql Folder/baz
```

If you want to extract all `.sql` files :

```
tar xvf test.tar.gz --wildcards "*.sql"
```

Comment: You'll probably want to add quotes: `'*.sql'`.  Otherwise, the shell will perform expansion before the parameter is passed to `tar`.

Comment: You're right, I edited my answer. However, I tried these commands and everything works great (using GNU bash 4.3 and tar 1.27)

Comment: They only work because you don't have any `.sql` files in the current directory.

Comment: Oops, I forgot this case. Thanks !

Comment: Probably also want to explicitly name the archive file, in case there are multiple matches : `tar xzvf archive.tar.gz bla.sql`. Otherwise, shell wildcard matching will bite at some point. Maybe not today, but...